# Create entry in custom post type in wordpress with custom html form

Tags: wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

I have an html form and I want to save the submitted form data to `wordpress` custom post type and also send an e-mail, I want all the submitted form fields to be picked up automatically instead of manually adding it in the code as fields change in many different forms.

I do not want to use any plugin as all the forms are very complicated and I contains unique field types.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

form:

```
 <div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<!-- post name -->
<p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
</p>

<!-- post Category -->
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?></p>


<!-- post Content -->
<p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
<textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
</p>

<!-- post tags -->
<p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

the processing:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter a  title';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the content';
}
$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

// Add the content of the form to $post as an array
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $description,
    'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    => array($tags),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' => 'post_type_name'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);
//save the new post
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
//insert taxonomies
}
```